# Clicar num Item no recycleView e abrir activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

estou com duvidas na minha aplicação sobre o recycleView, gostaria que ao clicar em um item da lista fosse aberto uma activity com os demais dados de forma detalha... Alguem poderia me ajudar a compreender como fazer isso.
Agradeço desde já

Segue o codigo:

### Adapter

```
 public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//Imageloader
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

List<Noticia> noticias;

//Constructor da listView
public CardAdapter(List<Noticia> noticias, Context context){
    super();

    this.noticias = noticias;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.noticia_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Noticia noticia =  noticias.get(position);

    //Carregando os dados
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(noticia.getImage(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.cadeado, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    //Mostrando nas viws
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(noticia.getImage(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewNoticia.setText(noticia.getNoticia());
    holder.textViewData.setText(noticia.getData());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return noticias.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewNoticia;
    public TextView textViewData;


    //Inicializando viws
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewNoticia);
        textViewNoticia = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNoticia);
        textViewData = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
    }
 }
}
```

### Classe do volley

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
private static Context context;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
    if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
        customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
    }
    return customVolleyRequest;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        requestQueue.start();
    }
    return requestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return imageLoader;
 }
}
```

### Chamada do Recycle na aplicação

```
[...]
//REcycle View
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listNoticias = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    getData();

    //recyclerview
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
    }


    //Iniciando o adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listNoticias, this);

    // Adicionando o adapter na recycleView
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //Progress Bar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Mostrando Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    parseData(response);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //Se acabar os dados no servidor
                    Toast.makeText(morador.this, "Sem mais noticias", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//Vai pegar as informaçoes trazidas pelo volley
private void getData() {
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Contador incrementando
    requestCount++;
}

private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Objeto noticia
        Noticia noticia = new Noticia();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Pegando json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adicionando os dados nos objetos
            noticia.setImage(json.getString(Constants.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
           noticia.setNoticia(json.getString(Constants.TAG_NOTICIA));
            noticia.setData(json.getString(Constants.TAG_DATA));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adicionando na lista
        listNoticias.add(noticia);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 1) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        getData();
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso assim:

Criei uma interface como um listener:

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    void onItemClick(MeuObjeto meuObjeto);
}
```

Depois, no meu adapter, criei um construtor que recebe um listener do tipo `OnClickListener`. Esse objeto é onde você vai implementar o que deve ser feito quando clicar num item da lista.

Dentro da classe que representa seu ViewHolder, criei o seguinte método:

```
public void bind(final MeuObjeto meuObjeto, final OnClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(meuObjeto);
                }
            });
        }
```

Finalmente, no método onBindViewHolder, chamei o método bind:

```
holder.bind(sua_lista.get(position), listener);
```

Espero tê-lo ajudado.